# Real Time Google Analytics API - Identify user session

Tags: python-2.7, google-analytics-api

I'm retreiving event data using Real Time Google Analytics API, so as to trigger responses each time conditions are met - while the user navigates.

This is my actual query on Google Analytics Real Time API (which works perfectly!)

```
return service.data().realtime().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      metrics='rt:totalEvents',
      dimensions='rt:eventAction,rt:eventLabel,rt:eventCategory', 
      max_results='25').execute()
```

I'd like to show results grouped by each particular session or user. So as to trigger a message to this particular user if some conditions are met.

Is that possible? And if so, how do apply this criteria to this query?

Answer (score 0):

"Trigger a message to a particular user" would imply that you either have personally identifiable data stored in GA, which would violate Googles TOS, or that you map an anonymous ID (clientid or UserID or similar) to a key stored in an external database (which might be legally murky, depending on your legislation). Since I don't want to throw away the answer I have written before reading your question to the end :-) I am going to assume the latter.

So, is that possible? No, not really. By default GA does not identify neither an identifier for the user (client id or user id) nor for the session (a session identifier is present only in the BigQuery export schema).

The realtime API has a very limited set of dimensions (mostly I think because data aggregation does not happen in realtime), so you can't even use custom dimensions. Your only chance would be to overwrite one of the standard fields, i.e. campaign information.

Of course this destroys the original data in the field. So you should use an extra view for the API query, send a custom dimension with the user identifier along, and then use an advanced filter to copy the custom dimension value to a standard field (while you original data is safe in your other data views). This is a bit hackish, though.

Also the realtime API only displays the current hit per user, so you cannot group by user in the query in any case - you'd need to download and store the data to an external database and do your aggregation there.